# Обратный нумерованный список в HTML

Tags: html, css

Как сделать обратный список? 
Пример:
17. последний
16. последний
15. последний
14. последний
13. последний
12. последний

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вам надо только изменить порядок цифр, то для этого есть атрибут `reversed`.

```html
<ol reversed>
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item</li>
  <li>third item</li>
</ol>
```

Если вам надо изменить порядок цифр и контент, то можно сделать так.

```css
ol {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item</li>
  <li>third item</li>
</ol>
```

Обновление №1:
Первый вариант с `reversed` не работает ни в IE, ни в Edge http://caniuse.com/#feat=ol-reversed
Во втором варианте c `flexbox` в Firefox вместо цифр нули.

Comment: второй пример не работает в firefox. Вместо правильных цифр везде нули.

Comment: это явно проблема браузера, надо писать баг-репорт